# Local path generated by pkg-config package not found by Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, path, include, pkg-config

I'm trying to develop my first app with gtk-3 tool through Eclipse Neon 1.0
Searching on the Internet, I found it was rather to use the pkg-config tool in order to link and include all the libraries needed by GTK+.
Installed the package and installed GTK-3 through cygwin, pkg-config is able to find the include path into the directory

```
/usr/include/....
```

The gtk-3 libraries are located in C:\cygwin64\usr\incluse.... indeed.
However, once included, Eclipse isn't able to find the libraries:

```
Invalid project path: Include path not found (\usr\include\at-spi-2.0)
Invalid project path: Include path not found (\usr\include\at-spi2-atk\2.0)
Invalid project path: Include path not found (\usr\include\atk-1.0)
Invalid project path: Include path not found (\usr\include\cairo)
[and so on...]
```

I look into the *Environment* option under *Project Properties->C/C++ Build* and the variable CYGWIN_HOME that points to *C:\cygwin64*

I'm sorry for being inexperienced with such environment, I hope you can help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

AB

Comment: You should start eclipse from a cygwin shell probably.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried right now but it doesn't work